# UtF-8 gives extra string in German character

Tags: c#, utf-8

I have file name  testtäöüßÄÖÜ . I want to convert in UTF-8 using c#.

```
string test ="testtäöüß";
var bytes = new List<byte>(test.Length);
        foreach (var c in test)
            bytes.Add((byte)c);
        var retValue = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes.ToArray());
```

after running this code my output is : 'testt mit Umlaute äöü?x. where mit Umlaute is extra 
text.

Can anybody help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it a filename or a string value? Are you testing with "testtäöüßÄÖÜ" or "testtäöüß"? If I run your code as is, `retValue` is `testt����`. Something tells me, that is not your actual code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, Tseng means the following

Taken from: http://www.chilkatsoft.com/p/p_320.asp

```
        System.Text.Encoding utf_8 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

        // This is our Unicode string:
        string s_unicode = "abcéabc";

        // Convert a string to utf-8 bytes.
        byte[] utf8Bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s_unicode);

        // Convert utf-8 bytes to a string.
        string s_unicode2 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);

        MessageBox.Show(s_unicode2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. You can't cast an UTF-8 character to byte. UTF-8 for anything other than ASCII requires at least two bytes, byte can can't store this

Instead of creating a list, use

```
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (test);
```